# When Building a Character, if a skill proficiency is mentioned twice do i add the proficiency bonus twice?

Tags: dnd-5e, player-characters, proficiency

I'm building a character in the 5th edition and my background and class both mention survival proficiency, do i add the proficiency bonus twice or only once?

Comment: What system is it that you are using? Without that information, I'm afraid this is impossible to answer.

Comment: This *sounds* like it's probably 5th edition D&D. Is that the case? (If so, I believe we already have the answer to this question on the site, and we can provide a link to it.) You can [edit] your question to add what game it's about.

Comment: it is the 5th edition. im new to D&D and dont really know what im doing. i do have a friend that is a DM but we havent been able to get together to figure everything out.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What happens if I get the same skill from both my background and my class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/19790/23064)

Comment: No trouble! As I thought, we do conveniently already have an answer for this question. I've made this question into a link to that existing matching question, where you'll find the answer to yours. Thank you for contributing to our “web” of questions that lead to that set of answers. :)