# What happens when a race skill and a class skill is the same?

Tags: dnd-4e, skills

In D&D 4th edition, the PC of

- class Assassin gets training in Stealth,
- race Shade gets training in Stealth (Heroes of Shadow, page 121, "Practiced Sneak: You have training in Stealth.").

I checked the core rules, but could not find anything, (although I did not read everything) and I looked up answers on this forum and found an [answer related to D&D 5th edition](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19790/what-happens-if-i-get-the-same-skill-from-both-my-background-and-my-class).

How do overlapping trained skills work for the D&D 4th edition?

Comment: Normally race doesn't give a skill training. Where is the Shade race from?

Comment: Super relevant question, I added a citation to the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### It does not stack with itself, apparently

The general rule is that you can't benefit from a skill training twice:

> You can’t gain training in a skill more than once.
>
> *(PHB, Skill Training)*

A race normally gives you a +2 *skill bonus*, not a skill training. Racial skill bonus does stack with the class skill training. PHB explicitly says this in the "Skill Check Bonuses" block:

> Your base skill check bonus for a skill includes
> the following:
>
> - A +5 bonus if you’re trained in the skill

> In addition, some or all of the following factors might
> apply to your base skill check bonus:
>
> - Racial or feat bonuses

Therefore, +5 from the Stealth training plus +2 from the Stealth racial bonus give a total of +7.

However, the Shade race gives both Stealth training and Stealth +2 bonus. Since trained skills do not stack, a Shade Rogue still has the same +7 bonus.

Comment: Thanks, this is super useful! However, Shade gets training in Stealth, not a skill bonus: "Practiced Sneak: You have training in Stealth."

Comment: @Dyin I am not familiar with this supplement, but I suppose the +5 from training does not stack with itself. Let's wait for more answers.

Comment: enkryptor is correct, 4e doesn't have the rule 5e does for replacing overlapping skill trainings. In my opinion, it is an extremely reasonable houserule to allow it, but it would be a houserule.